# Grails - Execute Table Row Deletion depending on confirm() prompt message

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql, grails

I have a table that contains employees and this table has a Delete Button. When this button is pressed, the Row Deletion happens without any confirmation message.

So I attempted to add such a confirm() dialog prompt but I cannot properly control what happens, because no matter what I do, the Row Deletion always happens. This is because of the following code:

**.gsp page:**

```
<td class="text-center">
    <g:link controller="employee" action="deleteRecord" params="${[id: celldata.get('id')]}">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="getConfirmation();">Delete</button>
    /g:link>
</td>
```

**javascript code:**

```
function getConfirmation() {
    var retVal = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete ?");
    if( retVal == true ){
        alert("User wants to delete!");
        return true;
    }
    else{
        alert ("User does not want to delete!");
        return false;
    }
   }
```

No matter what I add to the prompt message, the deleteRecord function inside employeeController will always execute. How can I stop the deleteRecord function from executing according to the message from the confirm() prompt?

**Fiddle located [here](https://jsfiddle.net/vagg77/u1n3cuev/)**

Comment: Graills used to and probably still does ship out the default show.gsp with a delete function which does: `onclick="return confirm('${message(code: 'default.button.delete.confirm.message', default: 'Are you sure?')}');" `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may changes `onclick="getConfirmation();"` to `onclick="return getConfirmation();"` to prevent the default actions of click.

Without `return` the return value of your function `getConfirmation` won't be used.

If you do not return explicitly, you can pass the event to function and add `event.preventDefault();` to the function body.

Comment: wow, I expected a much harder solution to my issue, ummm thanks again @aristotll